# What is this toolbar icon called and how can I access it? (ANDROID)

Tags: android

I'm looking at the toolbar at the top here:

http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/10/digg11.jpg

Does anyone know what the icon on the top left is called and where I can find it? Also, is there anyway of adding this to my toolbar without using an ActionBar? For some reason ActionBar is deprecated for me and I have all sorts of trouble following tutorials since they all link the toolbar with ActionBar.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hamburger icon, which usually opens a navigation drawer.

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the action bar for that and just lay the background to the same color of your Activity background so it gives the illusion you have no Action bar. but if for some reason you insist in doing it without an Action Bar then use an image view and align it to parent top and to the left side.

And Just change your extends to AppCompatActivity so you can see your Action Bar